# Best way to define a completion handler for URLSession in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, urlsession

I have a call to a URLSession:

```
var someVar = "Are you in my scope?"
let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: updatePlaces)
```

Where updatePlaces is a function defined as:

```
 private func updatePlaces(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void
```

I split it up into another function because I really don't like having this as one large block of code with my "updatePlaces" function as a closure in my original session.dataTask. It just seems to be doing too much in one function. I want to split it up.

I can also make a closure using the syntax below, but I see no difference between this and the function (I understand a function is a special type of closure, and I see no difference):

```
lazy var updatePlaces: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void = {(data, response, error) in
```

However, earlier you saw I added `someVar` to the scope. With the function and the lazy var, I do not have access to `someVar`. However, if I make the closure inside the session.dataTask, someVar is captured and I can reference it per the docs:

> Closures can capture and store references to any constants and
>   variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as
>   closing over those constants and variables. Swift handles all of the
>   memory management of capturing for you.

So... I have two specific questions.

Are there ANY differences between my function declaration and my closure declaration and just passing that to completion handler.

Is there any way to capture the references in the original function if I don't define the closure in it? I'm guessing not.

And a more... generic question: What is the preferred way of handling this?